# Ajax o json no puede reiniciar, no muestra el select de MySQL en la tabla

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, datatables

Me salen estos errores  no me deja ver todos los datos en la tabla. pero sí en `JSON`

[image]

**ESTO SÍ FUNCIONA POR SEPARADO**

```
 <?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "mva_colegio";

$conectahugo = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);



$sql = "SELECT * FROM mva_servicios  WHERE estado_p = 1 ORDER BY  id_prod DESC;";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectahugo, $sql);

//si no hay reultado imprimimos que diga error
if (!$resultado) {
    die('Error no hay datos');
}else{
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $arreglo["data"][]= $data;
    }
//pasamos los datos json
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);


mysqli_close($conectahugo);


?>
```

esto si funciona , pero esto no , ¿ Cuál será el error ?

```
 <table id="dataalumnos" class="table table-hover">  
    <thead bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Carné</th>
            <th>Alumno </th>
            <th>Dirección </th>
            <th>Tel</th>
            <th>Encargado </th>
            <th>Registrado</th>
            <th class="text-center"> Acciones </th> 
        </tr>
   </thead>
 </table>
      </div> </div>
     </div>
 </div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>


    var listar = function(){
        var table = $("#dataalumnos").DataTable({

            "ajax":{
                "method":"POST",
                "url":"listar_servicios.php"
            },
            "columns":[
                {"data":"id_prod"},
                {"data":"descripcion_p"},
                {"data":"tipo_p"},
                {"data":"precio_p"},
                {"data":"estado_p"}
            ]
        });
    }


</script>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            listar();
    $('#dataalumnos').DataTable({
        language: {
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
    "sUrl":            "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Primero",
        "sLast":     "Último",
        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    }
        }
    });
});


    </script>





</body>
</html>
```

**¿Cuál será el Error ?**

Comment: El error es que estas instanciando $("#dataalumnos").DataTable({}) dos veces, por que ??

Comment: yo soy nuevo en esto, vi un video de como hacer la paginacion con jquery y luego estoy haciendo un listar con ajax viendo video, como lo debo hacer... me puedes ayudar, como deberia quedar el codigo sin que me salga error..

Comment: Te he publicado una respuesta si tienes dudas con gusto las resolveré, espero te funcione

Comment: lo copie todo tal cual como me lo publicaste... pero ahora me salie un alert con esto: ** DataTables warning: table id=dataalumnos - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te indica básicamente que estas instanciando dos veces **DataTable** a la misma tabla, entonces para solucionar esto puedes intentar haciendo un único script de esta manera:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    listar();

    function listar(){
        var table = $("#dataalumnos").DataTable({
            language: {
                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero",
                    "sLast":     "Último",
                    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            },
            "ajax":{
                "method":"POST",
                "url":"listar_servicios.php"
            },
            "columns":[
                {"data":"id_prod"},
                {"data":"descripcion_p"},
                {"data":"tipo_p"},
                {"data":"precio_p"},
                {"data":"estado_p"}
            ]
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: si funciona gracias muchas gracias que Dios te Bendiga...

Comment: Me alegra que funcionara, como resolviste el error que te salió de AJAX ? Qué era ?

Comment: de ultimo tu codigo bien, pero yo tenia el listar_servicios.php en otra carpeta. y solo le configure la direccion de la carpeta donde estaba. Gracias. Bendiciones. =)

Comment: Hola hola Camilo... una pregunta con este código, te cuento que yo hago un insert por ajax pero no me muestra los datos, si ingresan a la BD pero hasta que recargo la la pag, me muestra misdatos, que me aconsejas que debo hacer.

Comment: Hola @Carlos como estás haciendo el insert ? método convencional o ajax ?

Comment: ' $('#btnguardar_datos').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
            var datos=$('#guardar_servicio').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"ajax/insertar_servicio.php",
                data:datos,
                success:function(r){
                 $("#guardar_servicio").trigger('reset');
                 $("#mensaje_de_produc").html(r);
                 

                }

            });
              


        }); '

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @Carlos has creado una pregunta para esto? si no lo haz hecho te invito a que entres al [chat] y podamos hablar mejor por allá para poderte ayudar ya que los comentarios no son para esto